# All sets are equal. Where is a mistake?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For arbitrary two sets $A$ and $B$ we have 
$$
(A \cap B)\setminus (A \cup B)=(A \cap B)\cap \overline{A \cup B}=(A \cap B)\cap (\overline{A} \cap \overline{B})=(A \cap \overline{A}) \cap (B \cap \overline{B})=\varnothing.
$$

Since $(X\setminus Y=\varnothing) => X=Y $  we have that $A \cap B= A \cup B$  and it implies that $A=B.$

Where is my  mistake?

Comment: What is $\bar{A}$ supposed to be if $A$ is an arbitrary set? And why is $(A \cup \overline{A}) \cup (B \cup \overline{B})=\varnothing$?

Comment: Obviously in the second equation. Make a drawing.

Comment: The second equality in the second line is wrong. You changed "$A\cup B$" to "$A\cap B$".

Comment: It's not true that $(X\setminus Y=\varnothing) \Rightarrow X=Y $. What if $X\subset Y$?

Comment: Guys, it is true that $(A \cap B) \setminus (A \cup B) = \emptyset$, but this does not imply that $(A \cap B) = (A \cup B)$! It only implies that $(A \cap B) \subseteq (A \cup B)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$X\setminus Y=\emptyset$ does not imply $X=Y$, but $X\subseteq Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Your mistakes is are in the second line. Specifically
$$
(A \cup B)\setminus (A \cap B)=(A \cup B)\cap \overline{A \cap B}=(A \cup B)\cap (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B})
$$
but then
$$
(A \cup B)\cap (\overline{A} \cup \overline{B}) \ne (A \cup \overline{A}) \cup (B \cup \overline{B}) \, .
$$

Comment: sorry, I delete the line